# PHP echo javascript with PHP variable

Tags: php

I am currently displaying javascript via PHP echo:

```
        echo 'var currentInvoiceDataJSON = <?php echo json_encode($yearData_Invoices[$currentYear] ); ?>;';
```

However I get a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < error which I infer is related to the second

How can I get this resolved and there any other possibilities?

Some expert advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code ends as invalid Javascript code.

Here's what happens:

Your server echoes a string:

```
echo 'var currentInvoiceDataJSON = <?php echo json_encode($yearData_Invoices[$currentYear] ); ?>;';
```

Your browser now has:

```
var currentInvoiceDataJSON = <?php echo json_encode($yearData_Invoices[$currentYear] ); ?>;
```

Once your PHP script finishes running and echoes that first string, PHP cannot process the inner echo.

---

What I would do:

```
$data = json_encode($yearData_Invoices[$currentYear]);
echo 'var currentInvoiceDataJSON = ' . $data . ';';
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Serg - you're outlined method works just fine!

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
echo 'var currentInvoiceDataJSON = '.<?php echo json_encode($yearData_Invoices[$currentYear] ); ?>.';';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but give it a try:

```
echo "var currentInvoiceDataJSON = '".str_replace("'","\\'",json_encode($yearData_Invoices[$currentYear]))."';";
```

Answer (score 1):

just change to

```
echo "var currentInvoiceDataJSON = ".json_encode($yearData_Invoices[$currentYear] ).";";
```

and also be aware that single quoted strings in php don't interpolate variables so

```
$a = "Hello World";
echo '$a'; // outputs :  $a
echo "$a"; // outputs :  Hello World
```

and when you are in a php context